# Error when declaring NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to create a NSManagedObjectContext object. They error reads as follows:

> Expected specifier-qualifier-list
>   before 'NSManagedObjectContext'

and here is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FavouritesViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSArray *favourites;
  NSManagedObjectContext *context;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *favourites;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@end
```

Anyone know I might be missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you have forgotten to include the CoreData header in your file. Right after the line `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` you need another line that reads `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`. After this the file should compile fine. Also make sure that you have CoreData in your linked libraries, otherwise you will get runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@class NSManagedObject` above your interface directive. This will tell the compiler that NSManagedObject is a real class. You then need to have `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` in your .m file.